# Rails: Is it possible to import content from another website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Specifically, I would like to import the first block of text before the table of contents from a Wikipedia page (which is public domain).

Let's say I have a Model "Resource", with an attribute `x`, and `x` is a string that is a Wikipedia link (eg. `x: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanny_McDonald"`). The first block of text on every Wikipedia page is the group of `<p>...</p>`'s before `<div id="toc" class="toc">...</div>`.

Can I write code that copies the content of these `<p>...</p>`'s and writes it onto my website?

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [Web Scraping.](http://Web%20Scraping)
Ironically follow this wikipedia link and
consider the legal ramifications etc.

[Nokogiri](http://Nokogiri) is boss for this..

Install:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib
```

Usage:
There are methods to search using xpath or css which makes things simple.

```
# wiki_scraper.rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

# Load in the url.
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor"))

# Print the first <p> element
puts @doc.xpath("/html/body/p[1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HttpWebRequest, to retrieve the entire page, and then parse the html. There are tools available to convert html to xhtml, at which point you could use xml libraries to parse the xhtml.